# Compiling Glib Code on Ubuntu

Tags: glib

I'm trying to compile ARCCC (https://sourceforge.net/projects/arccc/) on Ubuntu 9.10, but I'm getting the make error "glib.h: No such file or directory", and the autoconfig script reports that Glib isn't installed. However, I have the libglib2.0-dev package installed, which appears to provide all the glib headers. Is there something missing/wrong with the Ubuntu package, or the Autoconf script incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arccc is quite old. The latest release is from 2003. It was built on Glib-1.2 and used 'glib-config' which was changed to [pkg-config](http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/wiki/) in Glib-2.0. Glib-2.0 also was an API breaking release. You will either have to rewrite arccc, compile it with Glib-1.2 (e.g. Gentoo Linux provides a slot for Glib-1) or find an alternative.

[Here](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2002-April/msg00178.html)'s a gtk-list entry about the Glib-1 -> Glib-2 problem.